# Codeigniter Trying to get property of non-object error in Login Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in codeignter. i am trying to make login-register with it. while checking `if($user -> email)` it giving error saying Trying to get property of non-object of this line. how can i get rid of it. i have successfully made register section, but when trying to logged in it giving error. the controller code is here,

```
public function home() {

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('session');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[5]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');

        $this->db->where(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));

        $query = $this->db->get();

        $user = $query->row();

        if ($user->email) {

            $this->session->set_flashdata("Success", "You have successfully logged in");

            $_SESSION['user_logged'] = TRUE;

            $_SESSION['username'] = $user->username;

            redirect('profile', 'refresh');
        } else {

            $this->session->set_flashdata("Error", "No such account in database");
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('login');
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: first check your ```$user``` having values or not. Also check it is array or object.

Comment: Might also be worth replacing `$_POST[]` with `$this->input->post()` as this does null checks for you.

Comment: MD5 is considered broken for security purposes and is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error when $user is blank means no record found for given user name and password. 
Use

```
 if(!empty($user->email)) instead of if ($user->email)
```

Comment: error is not showing, but can you explain why flash message is not showing, thanks